# Reordering list element in react js

Tags: reactjs, reorderlist

I am wondering how to re order a list element. Its like you have a list of an elements `li` and put the last element in the first place like the index of 10th would be placed in the index of 0

```
React.render(   <div>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li> //When an event fires, this item would go up to the first index   </div>,   document.getElementById('example') );
```

Comment: any snippet ? so we can understand context exactly .

Comment: Did you build `<li>` set dynamically   .i.e : from model (data coming from server ...etc) ?

Comment: Reorder the state of containing the array of values you are rendering.

Comment: @LexphilCaraig: and I just give you an answer accordingly. ..:)

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMISo I see your code there. And What if its not only to reverse it. What if its in the middle and you want it to put at th first place. Like a random position when an event fires that specific element would be placed at the first index. Any idea? :)

Comment: I guess you need a better example about what you want, how works that event? and the correct structure of your array.

Comment: for the record, your example has no `<ol>` wrapper for the `<li>`s - for correct HTML it should

Comment: I believe both of the answers on this question are wrong, as noted in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808074/reordering-a-list-of-elements-with-unique-keys-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment on Abdennour answer (you need to update an item regardless of its position), you cannot do such operation with an array of simple numbers, you need to index your values:

```
class MyList extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
         {this.props.items.map((item ,key) => 
             <li key={key}> {item}</li>
          )}
      </ul>
    )
  }

}


class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
      this.state= {
        listItems: [{id: 1, val: '1'}, {id: 2, val: '2'}, {id: 2, val: '2'}, {id: 3, val: '3'}]
      };
    }

    reverse = () => {
       this.setState({
         listItems: this.state.listItems.reverse()
       });
    }

    // You can ignore this, simple put some random value somewhere
    // In your case this would be the function that changes the value of one of the items, should of course be NOT random
    changeRandom = () => {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.listItems.length);
      const newList = this.state.listItems.slice();
      newList[index] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();

      this.setState({
        listItems: newList
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
             <MyList items={this.state.listItems.map(item => item.val)} />
          </div>
          <div> 
             <button onClick={reverse}>Reverse</button>
          </div>
          <div> 
             <button onClick={changeRandom}>Random Change</button>
          </div>

        </div>

       )
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup! I guess this settles it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shouldn't your `key` be `item.id` instead of the list item index?

Answer (score 2):

So, i assume you have two React components: one for the list, and the other is the main component (`App`) which includes the `list` as well as the button of reversing the list.

```js
class MyList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
         {this.props.items.map((item ,key) => 
             <li key={key}> {item}</li>
          )}
      </ul>
    )
  }

}
MyList.defaultProps= {items:[]};


class App extends React.Component{
    
    state= {
        listItems: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
     };

    onClick(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.setState({
         listItems: this.state.listItems.reverse()
       });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
             <MyList items={this.state.listItems} />
          </div>
          <div> 
             <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Reverse</button>
          </div>
        
        </div>
        
       )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> ,  document.getElementById('example'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<section id="example" />
```

Comment: What if the array gets updated by its index like the index of 3 would go to index of one and it should update the list accordingly.

Comment: It's always advised against using element's index as a key prop:

_"We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state."_

See official documentation -> https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys